# Why can't I execute JavaScript function inside the <script> tag that defines the .js source?

Tags: javascript

I am defining the source of a .js file and attempting to call a function from that file in the same  tag, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFunctionTest.js">
    testMethodCall();
</script>
```

The .js file just contains:

```
function testMethodCall(){
    window.alert("Hello there");
}
```

This doesn't work, I don't see the alert.

However, if I change the  tag to *two* tags, as below, then it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFunctionTest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    testMethodCall();
</script>
```

This seems pretty messy. Is there any reason the first one doesn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register an external file and use the content in it, both at a time inside `<script>` tags. Only either one is allowed.